# Testing for the existance of constants within a range object in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, constants

I am using the SpecialCells method of the Excel Range object on a given target range with the type set to xlCellTypeConstants.
Of course if the range I'm checking does not contain any constants, I get the run time error 1004.

I can solve this by trapping that error with an 'on error' statement but i'd like to avoid that when I can.
So I'm looking for some means to check my target range for the existence of constants in one of the cells before applying the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) method to it.

I can loop thru every cell in the target range an analyze its content (not null and first character not an equal sign) but I'm pretty sure there would be a more efficient way of doing this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Trapping the error is the best approach here - why do you prefer to avoid it?

Comment: `"more efficient way of doing this"`. Yes. Error handling on `SpecialCells`. If you were hellbent on not doing this way, then dumping the range formulae to an array is the most efficient loop. But use `SpecialCells`.

Comment: @Tim Williams  :  Finally went the way of the error trapping method.  But when at all possible, I like to avoid error trapping just in case I trap an unplanned error and dont have the proper code to deal with it.